# Vue - using components in Vue instance

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am new to `Vue.js` and I would like to know if this piece of my code is a proper approach?

so this is `Vue` part:

```
Vue.component('share-option', {
    props: ['text', 'func', 'icon'],
    template: '<div v-on:click="func" class="share-options__option">\
                    <img class="share-options__icon" v-bind:src="`/Resources/image/ico/` + icon" />\
                    <span class="share-options__text">{{text}}</span>\
                </div>'
});

var shareModule = new Vue({
    el: '#shareOptions',
    data: function () {
        return {
            optionOne: { text: 'option one', icon: 'ico_opt1.svg', func: this.sendOptionOne },
            optionOne: { text: 'option two', icon: 'ico_opt2.svg', func: this.sendOptionTwo }
        }
    },
    methods: {
        sendOptionOne: function () {
            console.log('one');
        },
        sendOptionTwo: function () {
            console.log('two');
        }
    }
});
```

and the I use it in `html` like this:

```
<share-option :text="optionOne.text" :func="optionOne.func" :icon="optionOne.icon"></share-option>
<share-option :text="optionTwo.text" :func="optionTwo.func" :icon="optionTwo.icon"></share-option>
```

Am I doing this right?

Answer (score 0):

Change your data in the vue instance to:

```
data: {
        optionOne: { text: 'option one', icon: 'ico_opt1.svg', func: this.sendOptionOne },
        optionTwo: { text: 'option two', icon: 'ico_opt2.svg', func: this.sendOptionTwo }
},
```

Or another option is to:

```
data: function () {
        return {
            optionOne: { text: 'option one', icon: 'ico_opt1.svg', func: this.sendOptionOne },
            optionOne: { text: 'option two', icon: 'ico_opt2.svg', func: this.sendOptionTwo }
        }
    }(),
```

The last `()` would execute the function in place and assign the returned object to the data property.

Though I am not sure what is the plan with the `:func` thing, this should still resolve the issue.

Hope it helps.